# How do I download the website activity file on Google Cloud Platfrom?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Background: 
I found that most of the clicks on Googles Ads are invalid and around 95% of the conversions are spmammers. Then I want to ask to get full refund, but Google Ads asked me:

> Web log file is log file automatically created and maintained by a web server. Every "hit" to the Web site, including each view of a HTML document, image or other object, is logged. The raw web log file format is essentially one line of text for each hit to the web site. In order to investigate further please share the Website Activity/ Web log report for the date range for which you got invalid clicks for more details please refer to the Web Developer.

Question: 
Could you help me to understand where I can download the web activity file? where is it? how does it call on GCF?

Many thanks,
Tany

I asked Google Cloud Flatfrom support and they didn't understand what their 'friends' from Google Ads want.

Comment: Hi Tany.  This is probably better suited for ServerFault, the server administrator SE site.  I've recommended it be migrated as it isn't a programming question and therefore is off-topic for StackOverflow usually.

Comment: I only see [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer) a day. But I don't have website with GoogleAds connected and I never tested this part.